# Dealing with the Pandorica Paradox

Tags: doctor-who

In season 5 of Doctor Who, the Doctor is sealed in the ultimate prison (the Pandorica).  It can only be opened from the outside (one wonders why the Pandorica would be designed to be opened after being sealed at all, but I digress).  The Doctor manages to escape by travelling to the past and leaving clues for his companions so that they can let him out so that he can travel to the past and leave clues for his companions so that they can let him out so that he can travel to the past and you can probably get the point I am trying to make now.  **How did the Doctor manage to get out of the Pandorica to set this infinite loop into motion?**

Comment: Wibbly-wobbly, timey-wimey?

Comment: Because terrible writing.

Comment: @Valorum To be fair, season 5 had some terrific writing.  It is by far my favourite season of new Who...but I cannot deny that this is incredibly lazy writing.  I used to expect better from Moffatt.

Comment: “I cannot deny that this is incredibly lazy writing” — lazy how? Time travel is fictional, it’s not like we’ve tried this sort of time travel in real life and established that it’s not the sort of time travel that can work. What sort of explanation would you want?

Comment: Time travel is fictional, but logic is not.  If I lock my keys in my car, I can't use my keys to open my car to get my keys to open my car to etc.  I'd want an explanation that makes ontological sense.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster The point of the ontological paradox is to present a story that is internally consistent but has no beginning nor end. It's similar to a stage magician's tricks; they lose some of their appeal if you know how they're done.

Comment: Interesting postulate @phyrfox.  However, let me propose a potential counter.  Are you familiar with the show "hustle"?  If not, give it a watch, it is fantastic.  The show focuses on a group of con-artists that exclusively con other con-artists.  They use elaborate plans and nuanced mind games to achieve their ends, and the audience is only shown their full plan by the end of each episode.  Not knowing their plan during the show is great, but if their plan is never revealed then it would be frustrating.  Not knowing how the doctor escaped is similarly frustrating to me.

Comment: I love how people call plots they don't understand "terrible writing". This is a brilliant example of a consistent time loop, or an onthological paradox. Moffat abused the concept in his time as showrunner, but this one, and "Blink" are probably the best.

Comment: But the loop in Blink has an obvious starting point.  The Angels sent the Doctor back in time so he left clues of Carrie Mulligan to help him get his TARDIS back.  Easy Peasy.  But the Pandorica situation is not so cut and dried.  The main problem with this loop is that it cannot start with the Doctor in the box, yet that is exactly where it does start.  Again, this is the equivalent of locking my keys in my car and using my keys to open my car to get my keys to open my car to etc.

Comment: Really? How did the Doctor made the DVD Easter Eggs? With Sally's script, which she got from...the DVD Easter eggs!! What is the starting point?

Comment: Her best friend was send back in time.  It is not unreasonable to assert that the Doctor drilled the friend for information about Sally, and in doing so devised the DVD strategy.

Comment: Nope, The Doctor got _all_ the info, including the full script, from Sally herself, who had compiled it all at the end of the episode and handed it to a version of The Doctor who had not yet been zapped by the angels, and was at the time dealing with 4 things.... and a lizard.

Comment: ...darn, you're right.  That makes so much less sense than him grilling the friend.  This is that Baron pulling himself out the swamp by his own hair all over again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a case of **the writer paradox**.

The events can only unfold because the events have already happened.

This type of paradox has been use multiple times throughout the series. But they clearly point it out in the episodes [Under The Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Lake) and [Before The Flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Before_the_Flood_(Doctor_Who)) in season 9.

In these episodes, the Doctor clearly insists on the fact that they experienced a paradox, but leaves it at that. And even though he followed the paradox, he never created it.

**On a meta level**
Events that are shown to us are only the most entertaining timeline/alternate reality. So every timeline where it is interesting to see this paradox happen, we see it.

> *Digression* : That's why we follow the Curtis family in the movie 2012, because they are the one who makes it. Similarly, we only see the reality where the Doctor makes it (most of the time).

**The Pandorica is a special case though**
Indeed, every reality where this paradox didn't happen has been destroyed. So the paradox *must* happen. So there is no other reality to show us.

Comment: Great answer.  My one quibble would be the fact that saying "the paradox must have happened" carries no explanatory power, and is instead a statement of fact.  But this is a small quibble as there may in-fact be no actual explanation.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster : True that it is not an explanation, but in this vision of the show where "we see only the interesting timelines" it is a particularity worth noting.

Comment: I could not agree more @Edelk

Comment: A great example of this paradox are the mini-episodes ["Space" and "Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_/_Time), aired during the 2011 BBC Comic Relief. The Doctor literally sets a looping event in motion by simply _expecting_ it to happen. He doesn't know which control he needs to use, until he realises he can find out from his future self, because his future self has already solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the reason the Doctor went back in time was because he had a mop and fez, and Rory pointed out that was how he looked in the past. This is what is referred to as a “temporal causality loop.” In other words, The Doctor getting freed from the Pandorica and him going back in time are both the cause AND effect of the other. It’s similar to the ending of the Doctor Who short “Time,” in which the TARDIS was inside itself but a little bit in the future, meaning if you entered it you would be transported slightly back in time. At the end, the Doctor needed to know which lever to push, and the future Doctor comes in and tells him, after which the present Doctor goes into the police box. Neither of these events could have happened without the other.